# Importing Chrome bookmarks from HDD

Tags: hard-drive, google-chrome, bookmarks

My old laptop crashed and I removed the perfectly working hard drive from  it and plugged it into a new machine to transfer files.

However, I cannot seem to find any of my bookmarks from Chrome to transfer.

I've seen that the way to do this is by by finding the "**C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default**" directory, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Here is exactly what I get when I plug the hard drive in: 
[image]

And here under the user I'd like to import the bookmarks from, there is no "AppData" folder anywhere.

[image]

Is there anyway of recovering the bookmarks?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Answer (score 1):

#### Where does Chrome save its bookmarks?

> Wondering where your Chrome bookmarks are stored? If you want to make
>   a copy of your bookmarks we recommend you export them as an HTML file
>   which can then easily be imported into other browsers. You can do this
>   by following these instructions:
>
> - Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
> - Select Bookmarks.
> - Select Bookmark manager.
> - Click the Organize menu in the manager.
> - Select Export bookmarks.
>
> Chrome will export the bookmarks as an HTML file
>
> Tip: You can use a simple text editor program to open this file
>
> However, if you're just wondering where they are on your Windows computer, they are located in
>
> ```
> ...\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks
> ```
>
> Full extensions might look like
>
> ```
> C:\Documents and Settings\<USER NAME>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> C:\Users\USER NAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
> ```

Source [Google Chrome Bookmarks Location](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/yWZeXbOmU80)

Answer (score 1):

Enable *show hidden files*, then you'll be able to see the folders (in your case Appdata).

You can do this by going into the **View** tab in Windows Explorer(see picture) or,
[image]

Click **Start**, type `Show hidden` and click on the first result:

[image]

Check the highlighted option, click **Apply>OK**.